# Partitioning of geometric net into equivalence classes

Tags: combinatorics

Fellow Puny Humans,

A *geometric net* is a system of points and lines that obeys three axioms:

1. Each line is a set of points.
2. Distinct line has at most one point in common.
3. If $p$ is a point and $L$ is a line with $p \notin L$, then there is exactly one line $M$ such that $p \in M$ and $L \cap M = \phi $.

And whenever $L \cap M = \phi$ we say that $L$ is parallel to $M$ i.e $L || M$.

So far so good.

I want to partition these lines of geometric net into *equivalence classes* with two lines in same class if they are *equal or parallel*. One can easily show that binary operation *equal or parallel* is an *equivalence relation*.

Let's say there are $m$ such classes, then how many points does a line have in each class? For a given line $l$ in any class,  if a point $p \in l$ then how many lines passes through $p$.

For example, if I partition them into two classes $CL_1$ and $CL_2$ of parallel or equal lines, then number of points on any line in $CL_1$ is equal to number of lines in $CL_2$. This implies that each point belongs to two line. Can this be extended to a case when number of classes are $m$ i.e. each point belong to $m$ lines? I am confused because I can not show it for the case when more than two lines passes through the same point.

This problem is from TAOCP 4(a) : *combinatorial searching* Problem 21. (Edision Wesly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $C_1,\dots,C_m$ be your equivalence classes. Suppose first that there is a point $p$ that is in more than $m$ lines; then there is some class $C_i$ such that $p$ is in two distinct lines in $C_i$. But that’s impossible, since the lines in $C_i$ are mutually parallel, so every point is in at most $m$ lines.

Now suppose that some point $p$ is in fewer than $m$ lines; then there is some class $C_i$ such that no line in $C_i$ contains $p$. Let $L\in C_i$; $p\notin L$, so by axiom (3) there is a line $M$ such that $p\in M$ and $M\,||\,C_i$. But then $p\in M\in C_i$, contradicting the assumption that no line in $C_i$ contains $p$. Thus, each point is in at least $m$ lines.

Putting the two pieces together, we see that every point of the net belongs to exactly $m$ lines.

Answer (score 0):

It is exactly the number of lines you have in a class, simply because *equal or parallel* is an equivalence relation. Let me clarify:

Say $C_1, C_2,\dots, C_m$ are your equivalence classes. Say $L\in C_i$ is a line in $C_i$, for some $i\in\{1,\dots,m\}$. Say $1\leq j \leq m$, $j\neq i$, and $M\in C_j$. If $L\cap M = \emptyset$, then $L$ is parallel to $M$, and so $L$ and $M$ must belong to the same class. In other words, $C_i\cap C_j\neq \emptyset$, or $C_i = C_j$ by equivalence. But by assumption, $i\neq j$, so $C_i\neq C_j$, and so $L$ must intersect $M$. By one of your axioms, it must intersect $M$ in only one point. By arbitrariness of $M$, $L$ must intersect every line in $C_j$ in only one point.